# Angular application doesn't use 'target' DNS specified in the proxy.conf file when deployed to GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, github, proxy, github-pages

I deployed an Angular 13 application to GitHub Pages, and I have a Spring backend deployed to a custom DNS, say: 'https://example.com.
In my proxy-conf file I have the following:

```
"/panel/*": {
      "target": "https://example.com",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true
}
```

Which works fine when running the app locally using `ng serve`, however when deployed to GHPages, all the Http requests are sent to

> https://myusername.github.io/panel/...

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Many thanks.

Comment: The proxy is not meant to be used in production.

Comment: Oh, then I seem to have the wrong idea. What can I do then? And are there any docs you recommend on this matter?